# Pandas - GroupBy with multiple outputs

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like this:

```
CITY     LOCATION     PRODUCT
CHICAGO  CHI1         A
CHICAGO  CHI1         B
CHICAGO  CHI4         C
NEWYORK  NY1          D
NEWYORK  NY2          E
NEWYORK  NY2          F
NEWYORK  NY2          G
ATLANTA  ATL1         H
ATLANTA  ATL1         I
```

And I want to get 2 different stats based on the same grouping.
The grouping is [CITY, LOCATION]. I want to be able to get the number of products per location as well as the name of the first product (in alphabetical order) for that location.

The result would be:

```
CITY     LOCATION     FIRST   COUNT
CHICAGO  CHI1         A       2
CHICAGO  CHI4         C       1
NEWYORK  NY1          D       1
NEWYORK  NY2          E       3
ATLANTA  ATL1         H       2
```

The only way I've managed to do this is by:

```
gb = data.groupby(['CITY', 'LOCATION'])
df = gb.max().join(other=gb.count(), how='left', on=['CITY', 'LOCATION'], rsuffix='_r')
```

But I'm sure there's a better way to re-use the same groupby() object without having to join 2 dataframes.

Something similar to SQL:

```
SELECT city, location, max(product), count(product) FROM table GROUP BY city, location
```

Is there a better way to this this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `agg`

```
df.groupby(['CITY', 'LOCATION'], sort=False).PRODUCT.agg(['min', 'count']).reset_index()

      CITY LOCATION min  count
0  CHICAGO     CHI1   A      2
1  CHICAGO     CHI4   C      1
2  NEWYORK      NY1   D      1
3  NEWYORK      NY2   E      3
4  ATLANTA     ATL1   H      2
```

Comment: or `agg(['first', 'count'])` as the names suggest?

Comment: OP says "first product (in alphabetical order)".  Using `'min'` ensures that.